# Gerar backup de um Servidor PostgreSQL com senha via linha de comando

Tags: postgresql, cmd, senhas

Estou precisando realizar um Backup de forma automática de um servidor PostgreSQL, tenho um comando que faz esse backup porém ele sempre me pede a senha e não encontrei um comando onde eu já possa determinar a senha do banco já no próprio *Script*. O comando que possuo é:

**pg_dump.exe --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5432 --username postgres --format Custom --file C:\Backup\Backup_dados.backup**

O que preciso é um comando onde eu já determine a senha de acesso, para que quando o comando for executado eu não precise de forma manual colocar a senha do banco. Se tiverem alguma ideia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar as variáveis abaixo para facilitar o entendimento do código:

```
REM IP do Servidor do PostgreSQL:
SET PGHOST=localhost

REM Porta de acesso ao PostgreSQL:
SET PGPORT=5432

REM Base de Dados que será feito backup:
SET PGDATABASE=dbname

REM Usuário da base de dados:
SET PGUSER=user

REM Senha da base de dados
SET PGPASSWORD=pass

REM Diretório de destino do arquivo de Backup:
SET DESTDIR=D:\Backup\

pg_dump.exe -F c -b -v -f %DESTDIR%_%PGDATABASE%.backup
```

Caso não queira utilizar as variáveis acima, adicione antes do seu comando de backup a seguinte linha que já resolve:

```
SET PGPASSWORD=pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Crie um arquivo texto '.pgpass' na pasta do usuario com a linha "hostname:port:database:username:password". P. ex.:

```
127.0.0.1:5432:<nome_database>:postgres:<password>
```

e no comando pg_dump acrescente a opcao *-w* ou *--no-password*
Caso queira utilizar outro nome de arquivo e pasta, coloque o caminho completo em uma variavel de ambiente do sistema operacional com o nome de *PGPASSFILE*.